# Кэш на редирект

Tags: редирект, php, кэширование

Здравствуйте!

Стоит задача при первом заходе человека на сайте отправить его на другой (на поддомен), что бы он потом смог вернуться.
Я так понимаю, что тут нужно творить дела с КЭШом.

Пробую так:

```
if (!isset($HTTP_COOKIE_VARS["red"])) {
    setcookie("red", "yes", time()+60*60);
    header ("Location: http://поддомен.домен.ru/");
}
```

Не работает.

Comment: @KoVaLsKy, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте вместо $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS использовать $_COOKIE

Comment: Да. помогло. Спасибо

Comment: KoVaLsKy, тогда нажмите галочку слева от ответа. =)